# Update Spark Dataframe row by row

Tags: loops, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-update

Consider the following table/dataframe:

```
|------------------|
|date       | value|
|------------------|
|2022-01-08 | 2    |
|2022-01-09 | 4    |
|2022-01-10 | 6    |
|2022-01-11 | 8    |
-------------------|
```

And the following SQL query:

```sql
WHILE (@start_date <= @end_date)
BEGIN
    update t1 set value = 
        IIF(ISNULL(avg_value,0) < 2, 0,1)
    from #table t1
    outer apply (
        select 
            top 1 value as avg_value
        FROM 
            #table t2
        WHERE
            value >= 2 AND
            t2.date < t1.date
        ORDER BY date DESC
    ) t3
    where t1.date = @start_date
    SET @start_date = dateadd(day,1, @start_date)
END
```

I know my output is:

```
|------------------------------|
|date       | value | avg_value|
|------------------------------|
|2022-01-08 | 0     | null     |
|2022-01-09 | 0     | 0        |
|2022-01-10 | 0     | 0        |
|2022-01-11 | 0     | 0        |
|------------------------------|
```

The query runs an `outer apply` for each date, so the table is updated line-by-line. It is worth mentioning that the value updated is retrieved within `outer apply`.

In Spark, I get the values from `outer apply` using `Window function` and store it in an auxiliary column:

```
|-------------------------------|
|date       | value | avg_value |
|-------------------------------|
|2022-01-08 | 0     | null      |
|2022-01-09 | 4     | 2         |
|2022-01-10 | 6     | 4         |
|2022-01-11 | 8     | 6         |
|-------------------------------|
```

Then I use `withColumn` to perform the update on `value` column, my output is:

```
|-------------------|
|date       | value |
|--------------------
|2022-01-08 | 0     |
|2022-01-09 | 1     |
|2022-01-10 | 1     |
|2022-01-11 | 1     |
|-------------------|
```

**I KNOW** my Spark output is different from SQL output, because SQL performs the update in each iteration, and in Spark's case I'm doing the update after all the `avg_value` are calculated.

**MY QUESTION IS:**

**Is there a way to perform this query without using while loops, more specifically, is there a way to use update row-by-row in Spark?**

My original DF has about 300K lines and I'm avoiding to use loops due to performance reasons.

Comment: It is hard to follow your question. Could you limit your explanation to your input and expected output and how you derive the value in the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say, you have 300K lines. I doubt all of them contain different dates, so I assume you have certain groups. The following is the example dataframe I will be using. I have intentionally added groups with different cases:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '2022-01-08', 2),    # 0
     (1, '2022-01-09', 4),    # 1
     (1, '2022-01-10', 6),    # 1
     (1, '2022-01-11', 8),    # 1

     (2, '2022-01-08', 0),    # 0
     (2, '2022-01-09', 2),    # 0
     (2, '2022-01-10', 6),    # 1

     (3, '2022-01-08', 4),    # 0
     (3, '2022-01-09', 6),    # 1
     (3, '2022-01-10', 8),    # 1

     (4, '2022-01-08', 0),    # 0
     (4, '2022-01-09', 6),    # 1
     (4, '2022-01-10', None), # 0
     (4, '2022-01-11', 6)],   # 1
    ['id', 'date', 'value'])
```

In comments, I have provided the expected result.

What I try to prove: *Spark is not intended to implement loops. Almost any logic could be rewritten not to use loops per se.*

---

**Window functions approach**

In the provided script, you have logic which could be rewritten to do the same, but using a simpler algorithm without looping: a window function and a conditional statement.

```py
w = W.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')
df.withColumn(
    'value',
    F.when((F.row_number().over(w) != 1) & (F.col('value') > 2), 1).otherwise(0)
).show()
# +---+----------+-----+
# |id |date      |value|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |1  |2022-01-08|0    |
# |1  |2022-01-09|1    |
# |1  |2022-01-10|1    |
# |1  |2022-01-11|1    |
# |2  |2022-01-08|0    |
# |2  |2022-01-09|0    |
# |2  |2022-01-10|1    |
# |3  |2022-01-08|0    |
# |3  |2022-01-09|1    |
# |3  |2022-01-10|1    |
# |4  |2022-01-08|0    |
# |4  |2022-01-09|1    |
# |4  |2022-01-10|0    |
# |4  |2022-01-11|1    |
# +---+----------+-----+
```

---

**"Loops" in higher-order function `aggregate`**

The function [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html#pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate) takes an array, "loops" through every element and returns one value (here, this value is made to be array too).

The lambda function performs `array_union`, which makes a union of arrays having identic schemas.

```py
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(F.array_sort(F.collect_list(F.struct('date', 'value'))).alias('a'))
df = df.withColumn(
    'a',
    F.slice(
        F.aggregate(
            'a',
            F.expr("array(struct(cast(null as string) date, 0 value))"),
            lambda acc, x: F.array_union(
                acc,
                F.array(x.withField(
                    'value',
                    F.when(F.element_at(acc, -1)['date'].isNotNull() & (x['value'] > 2), 1).otherwise(0)
                ))
            )
        ),
        2, F.size('a')
    )
)
df = df.selectExpr("id", "inline(a)")

df.show()
# +---+----------+-----+
# | id|      date|value|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |  1|2022-01-08|    0|
# |  1|2022-01-09|    1|
# |  1|2022-01-10|    1|
# |  1|2022-01-11|    1|
# |  2|2022-01-08|    0|
# |  2|2022-01-09|    0|
# |  2|2022-01-10|    1|
# |  3|2022-01-08|    0|
# |  3|2022-01-09|    1|
# |  3|2022-01-10|    1|
# |  4|2022-01-08|    0|
# |  4|2022-01-09|    1|
# |  4|2022-01-10|    0|
# |  4|2022-01-11|    1|
# +---+----------+-----+
```

This way you can "loop" through elements of an array. But be cautious regarding the size of the arrays, as they are contained in one cluster node.